# Form_Activated is messing up closing the program

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to bring two forms to the front when I activate them from the Task bar or via Alt+Tab. The problem is that I can't close the main form if the second one exists:

This is the code I use

```
   private void Haupt_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cardLibrary.Focus(); //Focus the second form
        this.Focus(); //refocus the first one
    }
```

What am I doing from?

EDIT: 
Haupt is the main form.
CardLib is variable in Haupt
this is how CardLib is called:

```
    private void cMenuOpenLibrary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Config.libOpen)
        {
            if (cardLibrary == null) cardLibrary = new CardLib(this);
            cardLibrary.Show();
            cardLibrary.Left = this.Left - cardLibrary.Width - 5;
            cardLibrary.Top = this.Top;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: Sry I was being dumb. Adding closing the CardLib via Haupt_FormClosed fixed it.

Comment: Probably better to show some code that opens the second form? are you using `ShowDialog()` ? This would explain why you cannot close the 'main form'. Why can the user not close the child and then the main form?

Comment: Use cardLibrary.Show(this) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling second form from

```
Second.ShowDialog();
```

then this will create this problem as a dialog retains focus until it is closed

Instead of

```
Second.ShowDialog();
```

use

```
Second.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

How can this.focus in second form focus the first form???

```
  this.Focus(); //refocus the first one
```